# Setting callback domain in django allauth

Tags: django, oauth, django-allauth

I have fargate containers , the one has `django` and the other has `nginx`.

And  `django` use allauth for login.
https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

In this case, when accessing OAuth allauth makes the callback url such as,

`127.0.0.1/callback/something`

However, Of course it doesn't work.

Callback url should be `example.com/callback/something`.

How can I set the callback domain?

---

My environment is

Django&uwsgi 127.0.0.1:8011 server

Nginx receive 80 request and proxy to 8011.

They are in the container on fargate.

Comment: *However, Of course it doesn't work.* - did you added port after your local IP eg. `http://127.0.0.1:8000/callback/something`

Comment: mmmmm, I feel confused.  browser jumps to `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth/oauthchooseaccount?client_id=&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A8011%2Fauth%2Fcomplete%2Fgoogle-oauth2%2F&state=b88mSwkg0cqdAsry9I2JphFScoWc1&response_type=code&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2~20email%20profile&flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow` then  redirect to `https://127.0.0.1:8011/auth/complete/google-oauth2/?state=b88mSwk8lWg0cqdAsry9I2JphFScoWc1&code=1puqdbS9kkrZ&scope=email+profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email~`, so it seems to trying to access the localmachine host.

Comment: I added my environment in article.

Comment: You've to check your redirect url inside your google console it shoul contain `http://127.0.0.1:8011` or `http://localhost:8011` when you request for token google will send code, id & token to specified redirect uri & you've to grab all these values from url.